# How to multiply each row in a tibble with a matrix to get standard deviation?

Tags: r, tibble

I have one tibble and one matrix. The tibble contains a large dataset of random weights between 0 and 1. Here just a small fraction of the original dataset (original dataset has 15.000 rows) with random numbers:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)

weights_ptf <- tibble(a = runif(10, min=0, max=1), b = runif(10, min=0, max=1), 
             c = runif(10, min=0, max=1), d = runif(10, min=0, max=1), e = runif(10, min=0, max=1))
```

The matrix is a covariance matrix. For the sake of simplification the matrix looks in this case like:

```
CovMat <- matrix( 
  c(runif(5, min=0.0001, max=0.0002), runif(5, min=0.0001, max=0.0002), runif(5, min=0.0001, max=0.0002), 
    runif(5, min=0.0001, max=0.0002), runif(5, min=0.0001, max=0.0002), runif(5, min=0.0001, max=0.0002)), 
    nrow=5, 
    ncol=5) 

colnames(CovMat) <- (c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
rownames(CovMat) <- (c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
```

I would like to calculate for each single row in `weights_ptf` the standard deviation according to the formula: `sqrt(t(wts) %*% (CovMat %*% wts))`. `wts` in this case would be each single row in `weights_ptf`.

I hope my problem is clear. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `set.seed(2L)` used for creating data

```
apply(weights_ptf, 1, function(x) sqrt(t(x) %*% (CovMat %*% x)))
# [1] 0.02935053 0.02150601 0.03854272 0.01795160 0.03706881 0.04465907 0.03659552 0.02438940 0.03720857 0.01956361
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works perfectly. My last question would be: Is there also a solution using dplyr ?

Comment: @Daniel_D, anytime you start doing `matrix` operations, most of `dplyr` is a little out of scope. If you need this in a `dplyr` pipeline, perhaps `weights_ptf %>% mutate(sd = apply(., 1, function(x) sqrt(t(x) %*% (CovMat %*% x))))`. It's not perfectly `dplyr`-pretty, but it is (imo) far more efficient than wrangling `rowwise` or `purrr::` functions to do what you need. If there are other columns and you need to use a subset of the columns, then `weights_ptf %>% mutate(sd = apply(select(., a:e), 1, function(x) sqrt(t(x) %*% (CovMat %*% x))))` works too.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans.

Comment: @r2evans: Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated.